# Why is contour integration defined only for continuous functions?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration

Why is contour integration defined only for continuous functions?
Ordinary Riemann integration has no such stipulation; e.g., the Thomae function is discontinuous yet integrable.)

Comment: Because we really are interested in integrating holomorphic functions, for the most part.

Comment: I recently also consider this question. I think the continuous condition is too strong conpared with lebesgue integral.